# Replacing Numeric Characters through Indexing

Tags: string, powershell, indexing

I'm attempting to replace a character within a string, which in this case is a digit, with another digit that has been incremented by 1, and then adding it back to the original string and replacing the previous digit character.

In the below snippet, `sams2` should become `sams3` after this code has executed

However, I keep receiving the error, `Unable to index into an object of type System.String.` Is it not possible to replace characters through indexing?  Is there a better methodology for something like this?

```
$SAMAccountName = "sams2"
                $lastChar = $SAMAccountName.Length - 1

                    [int]$intNum = [convert]::ToInt32($SAMAccountName[$lastChar])
                    $convertedChar = [convert]::ToString($intNum + 1)
                    $SAMAccountName[$lastChar] = $convertedChar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a two step process. First we get the number off the end, then we replace that number in the string.

```
'sams2' |%{
    $Int = 1+ ($_ -replace "^.*?(\d+)$",'$1')
    $_ -replace "\d+$",$Int
}
```

Comment: I actually just discovered the '-replace' operator.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would only work if the incremental number is one digit.

```
$SAMAccountName = "sams2"
$partOne = $SAMAccountName.SubString(0, $SAMAccountName.Length - 1)
$partTwo = [int]$SAMAccountName.SubString($SAMAccountName.Length - 1, 1) + 1
$SAMAccountName = "$partOne$partTwo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try regular expressions and groups and then be able to handle multi-digits for free...

```
$SAMAccountName = "sam2"
# use regex101.com for help with regular expressions
if ($SAMAccountName -match "(.*?)(\d+)")
{
    # uncomment for debugging
    #$Matches
    $newSAMAccountName = $Matches[1] + (([int]$Matches[2])+1)
    $newSAMAccountName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note in your code:

1. Strings are immutable. New instance of string is created every time some change is made.
2. Use StringBuilder to manipulate individual chars.
3. Make sure you have compatible types. String is not char.

Take a look at following snippet:

```
$SAMAccountName = "sams2"
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]$SAMAccountName
$lastChar = $SAMAccountName.Length - 1
[int]$intNum = [convert]::ToInt32($SAMAccountName[$lastChar])
$covertedChar = [convert]::ToChar($intNum + 1)
$sb[$lastChar] = $covertedChar
[string]$sb
```

You can also use another metod, like following one:

```
$SAMAccountName = "sams2"
$SAMAccountName.Substring(0, $SAMAccountName.Length-1)+([int]$SAMAccountName.Substring($SAMAccountName.Length-1, 1)+1)
```